# Unable to edit and save .emacs file. Error; Symbol’s function definition is void: auto-update-file-header

Tags: macos, emacs, ide

I was messing around with my .emacs file, when suddenly something happened. I could not edit the .emacs file. Every time I try and modify the file then save, it gives me this error:

> Symbol’s function definition is void: auto-update-file-header.

I have tried to delete the .emacs file itself but it keeps coming back every time I launch emacs again.

Here is what my .emacs file contains:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-names-vector
   ["#212526" "#ff4b4b" "#b4fa70" "#fce94f" "#729fcf" "#e090d7" "#8cc4ff" "#eeeeec"])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (manoj-dark)))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (color-identifiers-mode flycheck))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("MELPA Stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-refresh-contents)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-color-identifiers-mode)
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "/Users/kjr132/.emacs.d/themes")
(set-cursor-color "#0a9dff")
(provide 'init-themes)
(add-to-list 'load-path' "~/.emacs.d/")
(package-install 'color-identifiers-mode)
(autoload 'auto-make-header "header2")     
(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'auto-update-file-header)     
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)     
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'auto-make-header)     
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(defun my-compilation-hook ()
  (when (not (get-buffer-window "*compilation*"))
    (save-selected-window
      (save-excursion
        (let* ((w (split-window-vertically))
               (h (window-height w)))
          (select-window w)
          (switch-to-buffer "*compilation*")
          (shrink-window (- h compilation-window-height)))))))
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'my-compilation-hook)
```

Comment: That is file is required by emacs, otherways it won't recreate itself. I think you're doomed ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual bug is that you apparently undefined `auto-update-file-header` which is run from `write-file-hooks`.  So every time you tried to write something to disk, Emacs would throw an error.

Maybe remove the `write-file-hooks` line in your `.emacs` file from a different editor, or using `emacs -Q`.  Or if you're brave, try

```
(remove-hook 'write-file-hooks 'auto-update-file-header)
```

in your running Emacs, and see if you can recover.

Comment: I tried to google for functions of this name but came up blank, so I'm guessing it's a local addition of yours.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I prefer even `vi` over `nano`. In modern `vi`, arrow keys should work, and you can remove a line with `d d`. (`u` to undo if you remove the wrong one!) Exit with Esc `:wq` or to quit without writing anything (maybe to start over without saving) `:q!`

Comment: I tried using another editor to delete that line but again, it comes back, nothing i do to it makes it change.

Comment: Emacs by itself should not do that, do you have other running Emacs processes which are still active and perhaps somehow rigged to auto-save?

Comment: yeah i figured it out, i modified the .emacs file then loaded it, then i saved it. idk why i could not modify and save.

Answer (score 0):

The message is illustrative.

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: auto-update-file-header
```

Such a message is indicative of the nature of symbols in Emacs lisp, as they have 4 individual components or cells, as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html#Symbol-Components).

The problem isn't with this piece of code, but rather no lambda expression can be resolved for this symbol.  See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html) for how symbol function indirection works in Emacs.

I'd prefer to just add the hook if there's a function accessible via the symbol, or otherwise just do nothing [with a message to that effect].

```
(if (symbol-function 'auto-update-file-header)
  (add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'auto-update-file-header)
 (message "Symbol 'auto-update-file-header has void function definition.
Maybe define one?"))
```